# ul margin different in ie7 ie6 then other browsers

Tags: css

i have this css for a ul list menu

```
#header-container #header ul.top-nav
{
    float: left;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 10px;
}
#header-container #header ul.top-nav li
{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
    border-right: 1px solid #008cd3;
    line-height: 15px;
}
```

in ie6 and 7 it seems that the margin-bottom is only 19px on the ul. i am using a reset.css file. i took the margin-bottom off and put a fixed height of 36px and this lines everything up across browsers. this however doesnt seem like a hack.

anyone come across this before?

```
 <div id="header-container">

    <div id="header">

        <a href="/" class="logo">esPAY</a>

        <ul class="top-nav">

            <li><a href="">adam wright</a></li>

            <li><a href="">Links</a></li>

            <li><a href="">Help</a></li>

            <li class="last"><a href="">Logout</a></li>

        </ul>

        <div id="TabStrip1" class="RadTabStrip RadTabStrip_esPay RadTabStripTop_esPay">
```

...menu code telerik..

```
/* Header */
```

## header-container

{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: transparent url('Images/navbg.gif') top left repeat-x;
    height: auto;
}

```
#header-container #header
{
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}

    /* Header / Logo */
    #header-container #header a.logo
    {
        width: 200px;
        height: 53px;
        text-indent: -5000px;
        background: url('Images/logo.gif') left top repeat;
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        right: 0;
    }

    /* Header / Top Navigation */
    #header-container #header ul.top-nav
    {
        float:left;
        margin: 20px 0 20px 10px;             

    }

        #header-container #header ul.top-nav li
        {
            float: left;
            margin-right: 8px;
            border-right: 1px solid #008cd3;
            line-height: 15px;

        }

        #header-container #header ul.top-nav li.last
        {
            border-right: none;
        }

            #header-container #header ul.top-nav li a
            {
                font-size: 1.2em;
                color: #008cd3;
                margin-right: 8px;
            }

            #header-container #header ul.top-nav li a:hover
            {
                text-decoration: none;
            }
```

Comment: The cause could be from some element or CSS completely unrelated to the small amount you shared in your question. A link to a live page is my preferred way to try to debug these types of issues.

Comment: You could try to use reset CSS http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: i am using the reset.css from there. i've stripped the page out so its just that code and the code below it which would not affect it

Comment: Are you using a doctype? Without the complete markup or a link, anything we say is just a wild guess.

Comment: @Adam Wright: Edit the complete code for the test file into your question. Or better, stick it on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com) (make sure the problem still occurs).

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

This looks similar to the double margin bug. Try to add `display:inline` to your floated elements or `*display:inline` to target only ie 6,7 without conditional comments, that how it usually gets solved but that happens on sides usually not on bottom.

Comment: `"but that happens on sides usually not on bottom"` - you said it.

Comment: Well hard to debug without an example. If you really want it solved put and example online.